# Unable to load .glb (GLTF) in a scene of GIScene.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, html, three-js

I would like to load a .glb file, which is the binary format of GLTF in a scene of GIScene.js (https://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/).

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GIScene.js Scene</title>
    <script src = "three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="GIScene_1.0.1/GIScene_min_1.0.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>GIScene.js - Scene</h1>
    <div id="scene"></div>
    <script>

        //create a new scene
        var scene = new GIScene.Scene('scene');

        import { GLTFLoader } from 'three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'; 
        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load( 'data/570.glb', function ( gltf ) {
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        gltf.asset; // Object
        }, undefined, function ( error ) {
        console.error( error );
        } );

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using this code, nothing is loaded in the scene of GIScene.js. I know that we can load a GLTF and/or GLB file using three.js. I am not sure if we can load a GLTF and/or GLB file in GIScene.js, even though GIScene.js is based on three.js. Can someone explain how to solve this issue, if it is possible.

Comment: from examples looks like you need to define the format  http://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/docs/v1.0.2/classes/GIScene.Format.html

Comment: @Mapperz Are you able to find a working example to load a .glb / .gltf, or .obj file using GIScene.js ? I am unable to find that.

Comment: https://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/examples/index.html

Comment: @Mapperz 1. In GIScene.Format Class (http://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/docs/v1.0.2/classes/GIScene.Format.html), I am unable to find .gltf or .glb format. Thankfully, there is .obj format which can be taken into consideration is specified in this link, but I prefer to use .glb format. 2. In the link for expamples (https://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/examples/index.html), I can't find an example code for loading a .glb or even a .obj file into a scene of GIScene.js. Instead, the examples given are using others like JSON. What I am looking for is an example code which loads .glb file.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working", and what error(s) do you see? You should load the GLTFLoader file from a script, to match how you're loading the three.js library... like `<script src="three.js-master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>`. The `gltf.scene` object is just a normal three.js `Group`... it should work the same as the result of any other loader that returns a Group, Object3D, or Mesh.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy My question is regarding whether we can use the GLTFLoader.js of three.js for loading a GLTF and/or GLB file inside a scene of GIScene.js ? Even though GIScene.js is based on three.js, I am unable to find any examples and/or statements regarding how to use GLTFLoader.js for loading a GLTF and/or GLB file inside a scene of GIScene.js, if it is possible. Moreover, GLTF and/or GLB is not an inbuilt supported format in GIScene.js as per http://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/docs/v1.0.2/classes/GIScene.Format.html.

Comment: No, GIScene doesn't understand GLTF/GLB. I think it _should_ have a way to load a `THREE.Mesh` directly (it must, if it can load other formats that create Meshes?), but I can't find anything like that in the documentation. If you can figure that out, you can pass in the Meshes that GLTFLoader creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/docs/v1.0.2/classes/GIScene.Format.html, the supported formats by GIScene.js are CTM, JSON, OBJ etc, but GLTF and/or GLB format is therefore not supported by GIScene.js. Moreover, the examples as given in https://giscience.github.io/GIScene.js/examples/index.html are only using CTM and JSON formats for visualization inside a scene of GIScene.js. So, there is no inbuilt loader of GLTF and/or GLB format files for GIScene.js. I am not sure if we can use three.js GLTFLoader.js for loading a GLTF and/or GLB file in a scene of GIScene.js because I am unable to find any such examples.